# LiveCycle Font not rendering properly

Tags: pdf, livecycle

I have installed Adobe LiveCycle ES4 using Default Settings on my system and i am using the GeneratePDFService for converting a URL to PDF.

The Logic is working properly but the problem is in the output PDF which is generated after conversion, the problem is, here in we are using Marathi Font, but after conversion only the Numerals/Numbers are displayed properly in Marathi in the PDF generated, instead of the whole Page.

in the page, we have used CSS font-face reference too and also tried implementing the font inline, but of no use.

The font used too is installed in the Windows\Fonts Folder.

Looking for favorable replies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason as I was using these services, it was working.Anyway I have a solution. For chrome ie and ff you can install save as pdf(webpage save as pdf) services.you can check for browser plugins or extensions for this.This will help you.For ie i think already a save as pdf feature is available.

Comment: The issue is with the font which is not rendered, PDf is generated properly. English characters are rendered properly but local font, is rendering empty characters not even junk characters. It came to notice that LS ES4 is not reading/rendering the font, how to configure the same in LS ES4.